# Nodewebkit app takes time to load

Tags: node.js, windows, node-webkit

I'm making my first desktop application with node-webkit in windows.
I compressed the folder of the application, then I changed its extension to ".nw" and I generated an executable.
The problem is that when I run the app, It takes long time to start (loading + white background of the window).
Is there a solution like showing a splash screen when loading or someting like that ?
I need your help please !

Answer (score 0):

You could create a launcher app and use the launcher app to start your [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) app and while [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) app loads the launcher shows the splash screen and when your [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) app is done loading it will kill the launcher process.

but it will be much faster if you don't compress is to .nw file specially when its a large file.